# I created custom nest js guard which is running before every request and I have added a property called all() on the request in that guard

Tags: nestjs

I have created a interface which is extending the request (of express)
I m adding property  called all() in it
which contains the body , query and params in it

```
import { Request as BaseRequest } from 'express';

export interface Request extends BaseRequest {
 
  all(): Record<string, any>;

}
```

this is the interface
which is extending the express request
and i m adding this all() property using the guard
this is the implementation of it

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    this.requestHelper(context.switchToHttp().getRequest());
    return true;
  }

  
  requestHelper(request: any): any {
    const all = function (): Record<string, any> {
      return {
        ...request.query,
        ...request.body,
        ...request.params,
      };
    };
    request.all = all;

    return request;
  }
}
```

in the main.ts file i have used this guard

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestGuard } from './core/guards/request.guard';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );

  app.useGlobalGuards(new RequestGuard());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and i have tried consoling the all() property in the guard and it's working
its mean request is flowing in it

when i try to get this all() property in my controller then it showing

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')
```

That's how i m calling it

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Param,
  Body,
  Req,
  Res,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestGuard } from 'src/core/guards/request.guard';
import { Request } from 'src/core/http/Request';
import { Response } from 'src/core/http/Response';


@UseGuards(RequestGuard)
@Controller('customers')
export class CustomersController {
  constructor(private customersService: CustomersService) {}
  @Get('/order-data/:id')
  async OrderData(@Param('id') id: string, req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    console.log(req.all());
    const data = await this.customersService.allOrdersData(parseInt(id));
    return data;
  }


}
```

I m calling the route localhost:3000/customers/order-data/1

```
console.log(req.all());
```

It should print {id:{'1'}}
But it's giving error
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `@Req()` for your `req` property in the `OrderData` method.

Comment: ooo lol how can I forgot it xD...thank you